# How do I display a message onscreen whenever someone logs into my Minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am new to running a server with Apex hosting. I want to display a simple message at the center of the screen whenever someone logs into the server. How do I do this?

I would like a solution for both Java and Bedrock.

Comment: With 'onscreen' you mean in chat or as a [`/title`](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Commands/title)?

Comment: @IceFreez3r yes I think so. I can't see how to display this automatically when someone logs into the server.

Comment: @C26 They were asking which one you wanted: As a message in chat, or as a large block of text directly in the center of the screen?

Comment: @Corsaka oh sorry, I meant a block of text in the centre of the screen :)

Comment: Don't Minecraft servers already do this by default? (The "<player> has joined" and "<player> has left" messages)

Answer (score 2):

## Java Edition:

First create a scoreboard to track new players:

```
scoreboard objectives add LeaveGame custom:leave_game
```

Then check in a ticking function if someone has not a score of 0 and if yes, display a title (a message in the middle of the screen) with the player name to them:

```
execute as @a unless score @s LeaveGame matches 0 run title @a title [{"selector":"@s"},{"text":" logged in"}]
scoreboard players set @a LeaveGame 0
```

## Bedrock Edition

I never played Bedrock Edition, but according to the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/scoreboard#add) scoreboards can only use the `dummy` criterion, which makes the concept above impossible. If it's enough that the title only appears once, when a new player joins, you can use a tag:

```
execute @a[tag=!Tagged] ~ ~ ~ title @a title [{"selector":"@s"},{"text":" logged in"}]
tag @a[tag=!Tagged] add Tagged
```

Not tested, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: If you're running a Spigot server over Geyser/Floodgate (basically have a protocol translator), ignore the Bedrock answer (use the host server answer).

Comment: This is great, thank you, but how do I make it a display a message in the centre of the screen all the time at login regardless of level/score?

Comment: I'm not sure, if I understand you correctly. The scoreboard updates automatically every time a player leaves the game. This means, that completely new players don't have a score and other players have a score of 1, when they login. It doesn't require you to manually set a score.